# AWS Chime SDK - CORS and ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a react app and am working on following the [getting started guide](https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/modules/gettingstarted.html) for AWS Chime. I've installed the aws-sdk and amazon-chime-sdk-js. I run this code to create the meeting:

```
    try {
      const meeting = await chime.createMeeting({
        ClientRequestToken: this.state.requestID,
        MediaRegion: region,
      }).promise();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

This throws an error though and the request is never completed. On Firefox I get this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://chime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/meetings. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

And on Chrome I get:

```
POST https://chime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/meetings net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I thought I had enabled CORS on my server, it's a Django app. Any ideas how I can solve this issue? Thanks!